# Нужна ли запятая перед «даже»?

Tags: пунктуация

Он надеялся, что когда-нибудь удасться найти дом получше заправки или лесопилки, где не помещался почти никто даже с учетом четырех припаркованных трейлеров.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: @user195813 _...когда-нибудь удастся найти дом..._ **Удастся** — пишется без мягкого знака. https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/udastsia-kak-pishetsya.html

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна.
"*даже с учетом четырех припаркованных трейлеров*" — присоединительная конструкция.

ДАЖЕ
2. Союз. Присоединяет предложение или член предложения со значением уточнения, добавления. Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «даже» выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми:
*Погрелся, помылся, даже подфартило с родной бабой поластиться.

В комнате было тепло, даже жарко.*
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_148

Розенталь:
Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми (реже используются тире, точка, многоточие). Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами ***даже***, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, и (‘и притом’), да, да и, да и вообще, да и только и др.:
*Незаметным образом я привязался к доброму семейству, даже к кривому гарнизонному поручику.

Раздались крики разносчиков, продающих всякие, даже русские, журналы.

Карл Иваныч большую часть своего времени проводил за чтением, даже испортил им своё зрение.

Любая, даже самая сложная, проблема может быть изложена просто и доступно.

Тень, и даже не тень, а тьма была единственной краской, нужной и пригодной Гоголю для его цели…*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120